# How to use # symbol in terminal password

Tags: ruby, linux, macos

I need to add Ruby gem to geminabox source with

```
gem source -a https://login:my#pass@geminabox.my.domain.com/
```

But there is `#` in my password, and this symbol is treated as the beginning of a comment (and I can't change this password). I tried to use `\#` and `%23` but they do not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `gem source -a "https://login:my#pass@geminabox.my.domain.com/"`?

Comment: Stefan, yes, i tried it with single and double quotes.

Comment: Have you also tried `gem source -a "https://login:my#pa%23ss@geminabox.my.domain.com/"`? Because the quotes you need for the shell (it shall ignore the `#`) and the `%23` notation you need to escape it for the url-parser on the server side (it shall use a `#` in the password).

Comment: yep, tried this too and it didn't work. also tested any combination of quotes and \# and %23